# Cannot assign vector value to field in struct: expected one of 8 possible tokens

Tags: rust

I have this struct:

```rust
struct PaginatedTopics {
    docs: Vec<Topic>,
    pages: u32,
}
```

and I want to assign a vector of `Topic` type to it like this:

```rust
let topics = conn.query_map(
    r"SELECT id, title",
    |(id, title)| {
        Topic { id, title, ..Default::default() }
    });

let mut paginated_results = {
    docs: topics,
    pages: 0,
};
```

This is not working; I keep getting the error:

```
error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `.`, `::`, `;`, `<`, `?`, or `}`, found `,`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:17
  |
9 |     docs: topics,
  |         -       ^ expected one of 8 possible tokens
  |         |
  |         tried to parse a type due to this
```

I don't understand that error. It's a simple assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rust doesn't have anonymous structs, you have to provide their name:

```rust
let mut paginated_results = PaginatedTopics {
    docs: topics,
    pages: u32,
};
```

See [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-01-defining-structs.html) for more information.